# Escape JSON double quotes in Azure Pipeline

Tags: python, json, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass in Azure Pipeline Template JSON parameter as string but can't figure out how to make this right so i could do **json.loads** in main pipeline to convert string to JSON.

Template pipeline:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: P1-T_automation
    type: git
    name: One/P1-T_automation
    ref: afat
    
parameters:
- name: accountvars
  type: object
  default: |
    {
    "hostgroup1": {"account1": ["hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname3"]},
    "hostgroup2": {"account2": ["hostname4", "hostname5", "hostname6"]}
    }

extends:
  template: Pipelines/main.yaml@P1-T_automation
  parameters:
      accountvars: ${{ parameters.accountvars }}
```

Follwing task `- bash: echo "${{ parameters.accountvars }}"` in main pipeline gives me output without double quotes (which are required for JSON format):

```
{
hostgroup1: {account1: [hostname1, hostname2, hostname3]},
hostgroup2: {account2: [hostname4, hostname5, hostname6]}
}
```

if i make object type of parameter **string** i get the same output.

if i escape every double quote like this:

```
- name: accountvars
  type: string
  default: |
    {
    \"hostgroup1\": {\"account1\": [\"hostname1\", \"hostname2\", \"hostname3\"]},
    \"hostgroup2\": {\"account2\": [\"hostname4\", \"hostname5\", \"hostname6\"]}
    }
```

i get good ech on bash task:

```
{
"hostgroup1": {"account1": ["hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname3"]},
"hostgroup2": {"account2": ["hostname4", "hostname5", "hostname6"]}
}
```

but after passing it to python script as argument:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
          displayName: Create fake data
          inputs:
            scriptSource: filePath
            scriptPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/self/Pipelines/scripts/datain.py
            arguments: ${{ variables.first_var }} $(topicName) ${{ parameters.accountvars }}
            workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
            pythonInterpreter: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/python_venv/bin/python
```

in python script `print(sys.argv[3])` and `print(str(sys.argv[3]))` both gives me:

```
{
\hostgroup1": {"account1": ["hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname3"]},
"hostgroup2": {"account2": ["hostname4", "hostname5", "hostname6"]}
}
```

Why do first escaped double quotes is replaced with ''?

I need to make it string one-liner with double quotes to make this fit in json.loads in python script.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can try to use the expression "[**`convertToJson`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson)" to convert the value of the object type parameter to be a JSON content.

See bwlow example as reference:

- **azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: accountvars
  type: object
  default:
    hostgroup1:
      account1:
        - hostname1
        - hostname2
        - hostname3
    hostgroup2:
      account2:
        - hostname4
        - hostname5
        - hostname6

jobs:
- job: A
  displayName: 'Job A'
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Print parameter'
    env:
      ACCOUNT_VARS: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.accountvars) }}
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo "$ACCOUNT_VARS"
```

- **Result**
  [image]

On the **`PythonScript@0`** task, you can use the same method to map it as an **`env`** (environment variable).

Comment: not really sure how to use any type of task inside template pipeline. everytime i try to insert task, step etc. i get ``Unexpected property``

Comment: @gipcu I have updated my above answer with more details. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This did the work:

```
- name: accountvars
  type: string
  default: >-
    "{
    'hostgroup1': {'account1': ['hostname1', 'hostname2', 'hostname3']},
    'hostgroup2': {'account2': ['hostname4', 'hostname5', 'hostname6']}
    }"
```